# Where can I find nice Dark ReSharper (with Color identifiers = on) Themes?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, development-environment, color-scheme

I haven't come across any decent dark Visual Studio 2008 color themes with support for [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)'s *Color identifiers* turned on.

Have any been published?

Answer (score 11):

I created a dark theme that uses the additional color targets provided by Resharper.

[image]

It is [available for download here](http://drewnoakes.com/code/visual-studio-settings/visual-studio-resharper-dark-color-scheme.vssettings.txt).  Remove the `.txt` extension from the file and then import it into Visual Studio via *Tools > Import and Export Settings*.  This settings file only contains color settings, so it won't interfere with any other settings you may have configured.

Note that I exported this file from VS2010 with Resharper 5.1.  It may work in VS2008 (please post a comment if it does.)

Note too that you will have to check the *Color Identifiers* checkbox in the Resharper options.

Comment: I like this one, for the settings for http url identifier is properly colored to light blue, instead of that dark blue that could be barely seen on the dark background! Thanks

Comment: Well is this really good? no consistency between class names, hard to distinguish btw method names and keywords (and even certain class names)

Comment: @nawfal, I'm not sure what you mean by 'no consistency between class names'. Method and class names are different but similar, because they are easily distinguished by their usage. Extension methods get their own colours. Interfaces have slightly different colours as well. What do you feel is missing?

Comment: @DrewNoakes 1)No consistency: `MembershipCreateStatus`, `NotImplementedException` and `ActionResult`. 2)hard to distinguish between `public`, `ActionResult` and `Register` in first method.

Comment: @nawfal 1) `NotImplementedException` is orange in the same way that `TODO` and `BUG` comments are orange (not shown) -- they indicate something that requires the developer's attention. 2) that's a matter of taste. As I said, these are all easily distinguished by context. Of course you're free to edit this settings file.

Comment: @DrewNoakes regarding `NotImplementedException` I get it, but what about `MembershipCreateStatus` and `ActionResult`? And yes almost everything can be distinguished by the context even without any coloring at all, but to my personal taste this didn't look good among the plenty of ones there. Look out for solarized or obsidian, truly good! :)

Comment: @nawfal, could you post examples of them as answers to this question, with screenshots?

Comment: @DrewNoakes not sure if I would post another answer here. I already did which moderator Bill Lizard deleted, may be because it was a double post of another answer. Being a 20k+ member you might have the privilege to view it. Let me see if I will get time. Surely I'll let you know once I do. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find a Dark Side theme that was compatible with ReSharper so I made my own a while ago.  Everything works with the exception of when the debugger hits a large block such as an Exception: the block becomes white washed out. I've tried at length to find the color settings for debug background, but have been unsuccessful. It's a minor annoyance, but still readable all the same.

I've posted a copy of my [Visual Studio Dark Side Theme for Resharper](http://www.raregrooverider.com/post/2009/05/10/Visual-Studio-Dark-Side-Theme-for-Resharper.aspx) for download.

Enjoy!

**Edit**: Added screen shot:
[image: My Dark Side]
<sub>(source: [raregrooverider.com](http://www.raregrooverider.com/_custom/images/MyDarkSide-Preview.png))</sub>

Comment: unfortunately resharper make a type color by default as a dark blue and it's very hard to see it on the black.

Comment: ... yes, it doesn't change the color identifier colors.

Answer (score 4):

Ragnarok Grey at: http://winterdom.com/2007/10/ragnarokavs2005colorscheme is great.
The colors don't create too harsh of a contrast, and I like how the background isn't 100% black.  Very easy on the eyes.

[image]

Comment: pretty nice, but it doesn't include any ReSharper-Specific coloring, as asked.

Answer (score 2):

I've just added my current settings, dark that supports R#'s color identifiers, to a Hg repo at Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/visual-studio-with-resharper-color-identifiers-settings/source/browse/

[image]

Comment: I just added one. Readme here: http://code.google.com/p/visual-studio-with-resharper-color-identifiers-settings/

Comment: why don't you export only colors and fonts instead of your FULL settings of Visual Studio?

Comment: @inTagger: The main purpose is personal use, hence I want all settings. Upon import, make sure to only import the parts you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

[This one](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangingYourColorsInVisualStudioNETBlackVersusWhite.aspx)...

[image]

...and [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/06/Join-the-Dark-Side-of-Visual-Studio.aspx) seem pretty cool.

http://infinity88.com/images/blog/thedarkside.png

Comment: I use Scott Hansleman's as a base (first link) and it works for me with some minor tweaking

Comment: Neither of these take advantage of the additional colour targets that ReSharper supports.

Answer (score 0):

I like John Lam's Vibrant ink theme: http://www.iunknown.com/2007/06/vibrant_ink_vis.html

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to take advantage of the additional colour targets that ReSharper supports.